# ASP Post data from view (two models) to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, view, controller, viewmodel

I am trying to send data from view using post. I am using two models in one viewModel, but in controller the data are not accepted.

This is my **ViewModel** (my model is generated from DB by entity framework):

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using RychleSkody.Models;

namespace RychleSkody.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class LikvidaceDiagnoza
    {
        public LIKVIDACE LIKVIDACE { get; set; }
        public LIKVIDACE_DIAGNOZY LIKVIDACE_DIAGNOZY { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my **controller**:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(LikvidaceDiagnoza likvidace)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.LIKVIDACE.Add(likvidace.LIKVIDACE);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        ViewBag.ID_FREKVENCE = new SelectList(db.FREKVENCE, "ID_FREKVENCE", "NAZEV", likvidace.LIKVIDACE.ID_FREKVENCE);
        ViewBag.ID_SAZBY = new SelectList(db.SAZBA, "ID_SAZBY", "NAZEV", likvidace.LIKVIDACE.ID_SAZBY);
        ViewBag.ID_PRODUKTU = new SelectList(db.PRODUKT, "ID_PRODUKTU", "NAZEV", likvidace.LIKVIDACE.ID_PRODUKTU);
        ViewBag.ID_LIKVIDACE_STAV = new SelectList(db.LIKVIDACE_STAV, "ID_LIKVIDACE_STAV", "NAZEV", likvidace.LIKVIDACE.ID_LIKVIDACE_STAV);
        ViewBag.ID_TN_LIMITU = new SelectList(db.TN_LIMIT, "ID_TN_LIMITU", "ID_TN_LIMITU", likvidace.LIKVIDACE.ID_TN_LIMITU);
        ViewBag.ID_TN_POSOUZENI = new SelectList(db.TN_POSOUZENI, "ID_TN_POSOUZENI", "NAZEV", likvidace.LIKVIDACE.ID_TN_POSOUZENI);
        ViewBag.ID_UZIVATELE = new SelectList(db.UZIVATEL, "ID_UZIVATELE", "JMENO", likvidace.LIKVIDACE.ID_UZIVATELE);
        //ViewBag.ID_DIAGNOZY = new SelectList(db.DIAGNOZA, "ID_DIAGNOZY", "NAZEV"); //opravit VIEW a přepsat do podobného stylu
        ViewBag.VybraneDiagnozy = seznamVybranychDiagnoz;
        ViewBag.New = false;
        return View(likvidace);

    }
```

and this is my **view**:

```
@model RychleSkody.Models.ViewModels.LikvidaceDiagnoza

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>LIKVIDACE</legend>
        <div class="editor-label">
            DIAGNOZA
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LIKVIDACE_DIAGNOZY.ID_DIAGNOZY, ViewBag.ID_DIAGNOZY as SelectList, string.Empty)
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.LIKVIDACE_DIAGNOZY, ViewBag.ID_STRANY as SelectList, string.Empty)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ID_DIAGNOZY", ViewBag.ID_DIAGNOZY as SelectList, string.Empty)
            @Html.DropDownList("ID_STRANY", string.Empty)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("ID_DIAGNOZY", string.Empty)
            @Html.DropDownList("ID_STRANY", string.Empty)
        </div>
...
```

as you can see from view i have tried to find correct solution, but i have not been successful so far. Everytime i get null in controller's input variable **likvidace**.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Can't figure that one out, seems to work fine for me. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally i have found out "correct" (working) solution. I have tried to figure it out on a new project. It is working for me now. I hope this helps someone.

The problem here was in my create view

I have to use strongly typed helpers (DropDownListFor(model => model. ...) like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.LIKVIDACE.ID_UZIVATELE, ViewBag.ID_UZIVATELE as SelectList, String.Empty)
```

instead of:

```
@Html.DropDownList("ID_DIAGNOZY", string.Empty)
```